# What is better: reserve vector capacity, preallocate to size or push back in loop?

Tags: c++, stdvector

I have a function that takes a pointer to char array and segment size as input arguments and calls another function that requires a `std::array<std::string>`. The idea is that the input char array is "sectioned" into equal parts, and string array formed.

The input char array format is several smaller arrays (or strings) of determined size, concatenated togeather. These are not assumed zero-terminated, although they might be. Examples for segment size 5 and number of elements 10:

```
char k[] = "1234\0001234\0001234\0001234\0001234\0001234\0001234\0001234\0001234\0001234\000";
char m[] = "1234\00067890987654321\000234567809876\0005432\000\000\0003456789098";
char n[] = "12345678909876543211234567890987654321123456789098";
```

Length of all char arrays is 51 (segment * elements + 1). My goal is to make the function use resources efficiently, most importantly execution time.

Since there are many ways to skin a cat, I have two (or three) ways to tackle this, and the question is, which is "better"? By that I mean faster and less resource-wasteful. I am not a professional, so be patient with me.

Here, `values` is preallocated and then each string assigned a value.

```
void myfnc_1(void *a_src, uint32_t a_segment) {
    // a_segment = 5 for example
    size_t nSize = GetSize(); // another method, gets 10
    std::vector<std::string> values(nSize);
    char* v = a_src; // take k, n or m for example

    for (size_t i = 0; i < nSize; ++i) {
        values.at(i).assign(v, a_segment);
        v += a_segment;
    }
}
```

Here, the vector is not allocated, but each iteration a new string is added.

```
void myfnc_1(void *a_src, uint32_t a_segment) {
    size_t nSize = GetSize();
    std::vector<std::string> values();
    char* v = a_src;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < nSize; ++i) {
        values.push_back("");
        values.back().assign(v, a_segment);
        v += a_segment;
    }
}
```

There might be a third way, that's better. I'm not so experienced with vectors so I don't know exactly. Do the segment length and number of elements make a difference if they are usually large (5, 10) or small (100, 10000)?

First post, big fan :)

Comment: The most efficient way is to make an empty vector, reserve enough capacity and then push_back the values. (so there will be no copy)

Comment: If your data is completely known at compile time, it normally should be possible to create the data structures needed without any copy/move during runtime. If so think about a static initialization.

Comment: In your 1st example, since you initialised it with `nSize` elements, there is absolutely no point in wasting time indexing with `.at(i)` and bounds-checking the index each time, since it by definition must be valid there. Use `.operator[]`, which doesn't do unneeded checking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Better performance will be reached when avoiding dynamic reallocation, so try to have the vector memory be big enough to receive all elements.

Your first solution will be more efficient because if nSize is bigger than default vector capacity, the second one will need a reallocation to be able to store all elements.

As commented by Melkon, `reserve` is even better:

```
void myfnc_1(void *a_src, uint32_t a_segment) {
    size_t nSize = GetSize();
    std::vector<std::string> values;
    values.reserve( nSize );
    char* v = a_src;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < nSize; ++i) {
        values.push_back( std::string( v, a_segment ) );
        v += a_segment;
    }
}
```

Comment: Tho the first one will fill the vector with default values which is a waste. Reserving and pushing back the right values would be more efficient.

Comment: Thanks. Better that way?

Comment: Accepted as answer, because I think it was first? Idk yet how this works, so it's fair... Thanks for help!

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work . The bottom line is that you should accept the answer that you found to be the most helpful to you, personally.

Comment: I wouldn't assume `reserve` then `push_back` is faster than create the correct size then assign. I've seen a number of examples where the second option was faster. I think it might be because computers are fast at filling containers with defaults values, it might be because compilers often optimize that part out anyway and also although `push_back` won't need to reallocate, it still needs to check if it _should_ reallocate. I think the only way to know for sure is to measure.

Comment: Unless `a_segment` is small and you are benefitting from the small-string-optimization then this does not avoid reallocation because `std::string` will have to do an allocation internally at each `push_back`.

Answer (score 39):

## Adding elements to a vector

There are several ways to add data to a vector:

- create an empty vector, `push_back()` elements into it.
- create an empty vector, allocate some capacity with `reserve()`, then `push_back()` elements into it.
- create a vector of `n` elements, use indexing and copy-assignment.
- create an empty vector, `emplace_back()` elements into it.
- create an empty vector, allocate some capacity with `reserve()`, then `emplace_back()` elements into it.

There are other ways, e.g. creating the container with a pair of iterators, or filling it via standard library algorithms. I won't consider these here.

### General considerations

The following two considerations are important for the following analysis:

- **Avoid (re)allocations:** Memory allocation is slow. reallocation often involves copying everything that's already in the container to the new location.
- **Avoid unnecessary work:** It's better to construct the element you want than to default-construct, then assign. It's better to construct an element where you want it than to construct it elsewhere, then copy.

Other factors will also affect the efficiency of the chosen solution, but these are significant factors that we have direct control over. Other factors may become obvious through profiling your code.

### push_back()

Each `push_back()` copy-constructs an element in the vector from the argument to the `push_back()` call. If the vector `size() == capacity()`, a reallocation will be performed. This will usually (but may not always) double the capacity, and may result in copying *all* of the existing elements into new storage.

### push_back() with pre-allocation

Using `reserve()` allocates enough memory for the elements before we start. It's always worth doing this if you know (or have a reasonable guess for) the number of elements. If you're guessing, over-estimates are better than under-estimates.

The `push_back()` call will still use the copy constructor of the element type, but there shouldn't be any allocations, because the space is already provided. You just pay the cost of a single allocation during the `reserve()` call. If you do run over the existing capacity, `push_back()` will reallocate, often doubling the capacity. This is why an over-estimate for the size is better; you're less likely to get a reallocation, whereas with an under-estimate, not only will you likely reallocate, but you'll waste memory allocating almost twice as much as you needed!

Note that the "doubling capacity" behaviour is not specified by the standard, but it is a common implementation, designed to reduce the reallocation frequency when using `push_back()` for data sets of unknown size.

### indexing and element assignment

Here, we create a vector of the correct number of default-constructed elements, and then use the copy-assignment operator to replace them with the elements we want. This has only one allocation, but can be slow if copy-assignment does anything complicated. This doesn't really work for data sets of unknown (or only guessed) size; the element indexing is safe only if you know the index will never exceed `size()`, and you have to resort to `push_back()` or resizing if you need more. This isn't a good general solution, but it can work sometimes.

### emplace_back()

`emplace_back()` constructs the element in-place with the arguments to the `emplace_back()` call. This can often be faster than the equivalent `push_back()` (but not always). It still allocates in the same pattern as `push_back()`, reserving some capacity, filling it, then reallocating when more is needed. Much of the same argument applies, but you can make some gains from the construction method.

### emplace_back() with pre-allocation

This should be your go-to strategy for C++11 or later codebases. You gain the `emplace_back()` efficiency (where possible) and avoid repeated allocations. Of the mechanisms listed, this would be expected to be the fastest in most cases.

### A note on efficiency

Efficiency can be measured in several ways. Execution time is a common measure, but not always the most relevant. General advice about which strategy to use is based on experience and essentially "averages" the various effects to provide some reasonable statements about what to do first. As always, if any kind of efficiency is critical for your application, the only way to be sure you're optimising the right place is to **profile** your code, make changes, and then **profile** it again to demonstrate that the changes had the desired effect. Different data types, hardware, I/O requirements, etc. can all affect this kind of timing, and you will never know how those effects combine in your particular application until you **profile** it.

## Example

Live example: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/83d23c2d0dcee2ff

In this example, I fill a vector with 10,000 strings using each of the approaches listed above. I time each one and print the results.

This is similar to your question, but not identical; your results will differ!

Note that the `emplace_back()` with `reserve()` is the fastest, but the indexing & assignment is also quick here. This is likely because `std::string` has an efficient `swap()`, and its default constructor doesn't do much. The other approaches are an order of magnitude slower.

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using Clock = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;
using time_point = std::chrono::time_point<Clock>;

std::vector<std::string> strings = {"one", "two", "three", "four", "five"};

std::chrono::duration<double> vector_push_back(const size_t n) {
    time_point start, end;
    start = Clock::now();

    std::vector<std::string> v;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        v.push_back(strings[i % strings.size()]);
    }

    end = Clock::now();
    return end - start;
}

std::chrono::duration<double> vector_push_back_with_reserve(const size_t n) {
    time_point start, end;
    start = Clock::now();

    std::vector<std::string> v;
    v.reserve(n);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        v.push_back(strings[i % strings.size()]);
    }

    end = Clock::now();
    return end - start;
}

std::chrono::duration<double> vector_element_assignment(const size_t n) {
    time_point start, end;
    start = Clock::now();

    std::vector<std::string> v(n);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        v[i] = strings[i % strings.size()];
    }

    end = Clock::now();
    return end - start;
}

std::chrono::duration<double> vector_emplace_back(const size_t n) {
    time_point start, end;
    start = Clock::now();

    std::vector<std::string> v;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        v.emplace_back(strings[i % strings.size()]);
    }

    end = Clock::now();
    return end - start;
}

std::chrono::duration<double> vector_emplace_back_with_reserve(const size_t n) {
    time_point start, end;
    start = Clock::now();

    std::vector<std::string> v;
    v.reserve(n);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        v.emplace_back(strings[i % strings.size()]);
    }

    end = Clock::now();
    return end - start;
}

int main() {
    const size_t n = 10000;
    std::cout << "vector push_back: " << vector_push_back(n).count() << "\n";
    std::cout << "vector push_back with reserve: " << vector_push_back(n).count() << "\n";
    std::cout << "vector element assignment: " << vector_element_assignment(n).count() << "\n";
    std::cout << "vector emplace_back: " << vector_emplace_back(n).count() << "\n";
    std::cout << "vector emplace_back with reserve: " << vector_emplace_back_with_reserve(n).count() << "\n";
}
```

**Results:**

```
vector push_back: 0.00205563
vector push_back with reserve: 0.00152464
vector element assignment: 0.000610934
vector emplace_back: 0.00125141
vector emplace_back with reserve: 0.000545451
```

## Conclusions

For most new code, using `reserve()` and `emplace_back()` (or `push_back()` for older code) should give you a good first-approximation for efficiency. If it isn't enough, profile it and find out where the bottleneck is. It probably won't be where you think it is.

Comment: Timing results in debug mode may be interesting too, on PC at least (with _DEBUG set), differences are more sig,ificant I think (not reserving costs a lot)

Comment: @jpo38 – yeah, the optimiser can claw back some of the cost, and it's likely to also do unexpected things if you don't actually use values after computing them... so even the timings shown above should be taken with a pinch of salt. It just highlights all the more effectively the need to **profile** the actual application being optimised. Simple benchmarks like the above are enough for a general overview, but should not be taken as absolutes.

Comment: Interestingly, I [re-ran your benchmark](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/KpZYM9ImaQ2y4Ehy) with strings longer than 20 characters (to avoid small string optimization) and emplace (without reserve) came out fastest. I can't explain why.

Comment: @ChrisDrew – further evidence that it's necessary to profile a particular use-case, rather than relying on generally assumed "wisdoms" about what should be fastest. I can't explain why that particular result was obtained either. I guess there's some optimisation I can't immediately see.

Comment: @ChrisDrew I guess it has something to do with memory usage. If you change the execution order of `vector_emplace_back_with_reserve(n).count()` and `vector_emplace_back(n).count()`, [the result also changes](https://wandbox.org/permlink/mAwdvMPmgtynfZ4I).

Comment: @ChrisDrew [A quick benchmark](https://quick-bench.com/q/CjZBOO9yutZSPEd1rJ7mx_bpU_4) shows `reserve` indeed makes the program faster.

Answer (score 3):

[Do not use parentheses to invoke the default constructor.](/q/26036644/)

`push_back` requires extra reallocations each time capacity is exceeded. So option 2 can be improved by reserving enough space to avoid reallocations. It is also more efficient to directly push the string than to push an empty one and later on reassign. And there is a constructor for `std::string` which is very convenient for your needs : [*from sequence (5)*
**`string (const char* s, size_t n);`**](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/)

Regarding option 1: Preallocating the whole vector requires each element to be constructed once for initialization and yet another time for assignment. Better to reserve without constructing elements and directly `push_back` the ones you really want.

This is the code using those improvements :

```
void myfnc_1(void *a_src, uint32_t a_segment)
{
    std::vector<std::string> values;
    size_t nSize = GetSize( );
    values.reserve(nSize);
    char* v = static_cast<char*> ( a_src );

    for (size_t i = 0; i < nSize; ++i)
    {
        values.push_back( std::string( v, a_segment) );
        v += a_segment;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice comment on string constructor. This does clear some ambiguity, I think.

Comment: I fail to see how the linked question is related to the text?

Answer (score -3):

Just do whatever is easier to read and to maintain. Quite often, it's the fastest solution anyway.

And even if it isn't the fastest, who cares? Maybe your app will be 1% slower.

Comment: `reserve` prevents dynamic reallocation and will make push_back faster for huge loops. In Debug mode, time can be devided by two (in Release, it's less significant, but the different is greater than 1%)

Comment: I believe we partially use C++ because it's efficient, so saying for the performance "who cares" is kinda strange to me. If it would make the app 1% slower than this optimization is huge.

Comment: I agree with the sentiment here that speed isn't always the "better", as indicated in the question. It's *very* often worth trading speed for readability / reliability. But we don't know the context and they did specifically indicate speed as a metric

Comment: I agree that my answer is a bit short and unhelpful - perhaps I was a little simplistic. But in my experience, today's optimized code becomes tomorrow's slower code. As requirements change, the pressure points in your app will change and you would like to be able to change the design easily. "optimized" code is often difficult to change, and even buggy. The question isn't "what's fastest today?", but "what will be fastest over the lifetime of this app?".

Comment: @jpo38, `reserve` is good, because it can be added to a simple program without fuss. Anybody reading or writing knows that it has essentially no meaningful side effects and therefore it doesn't add to the complexity of the design. So, basically just write the simplest code and throw in the odd "no-op" such as `reserve` where appropriate.