# How is better handle element allocation with a Qvector<Qhash<QString,QString> >

Tags: qt

I have:

```
typedef QHash<QString,QString> CueTrack;
QVector<CueTrack> tracks;
```

Each QHash have to store 12 pairs.

The QVector should contain 0 to 99 elements, but I cannot know how many they will be in advance as it depends on data that will be read runtime from an external user file. On average they are expected to be about 10; in most cases are between 5 and 15; rarely are more than 20 and almost never more than 30 (but, in some very rare cases, they can reach up to 99).

I thought of 2 scenarios:

a) no initial sizing and resize when needed

```
typedef QHash<QString,QString> CueTrack;
QVector<CueTrack> tracks;
...
tracks.resize(i+1);
tracks[i]["cmd"] = "val";
...
```

b) initial sizing

```
typedef QHash<QString,QString> CueTrack;
QVector<CueTrack> tracks(99);
```

I am in doubt, and I would like to understand:

1. What is the preferred scenario, especially in terms of performance?
2. Is there any other possible scenario that is preferable?
3. Should `squeeze()` be used here? How and when?

Comment: Highly relevant, perhaps even duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32199388/what-is-better-reserve-vector-capacity-preallocate-to-size-or-push-back-in-loo/32200517 So, `reserve` the right size once you know it, presumably from reading the user file header, then simply `emplace_back` each element. `squeeze()` is not needed in this case. `QVector` doesn't have `emplace_back`, so you will be fine with `push_back`.

Comment: @replete - Thanks for the suggestion and the link. The only way I have to know the real size would be parse the whole file, but I prefer avoid doing this, so I will reserve the maximum size I expected (which should be 99). The Qt documentation says `push_back` is equivalent to `append`, so I think I will use the latter.

Answer (score 0):

An empty `QHash` doesn't take up much space, and 99 is (for a computer) a very small data set.

Furthermore, Qt containers have an exponential growth policy. When the allocated container space gets too small, it will be doubled.

So if you resize(+1), it will grow (about) in powers of two.

`QHash` has an advantage over `QMap` in that it can be preallocated, too.

*Probably* your best strategy would be:

```
tracks.reserve(20);

// When adding a new track:
tracks.resize(i+1);
tracks[i].reserve(12); // number of pairs
```

**But** as with all questions concerning performance: Profile, then ignore :-)