# Efficient std::vector initialization with another vector and map function

Tags: c++, vector

I have a question about std::vector initialization, but can't find a simple solution.

Imagine we have a vector with some data and a map function which should be applied to each element of this vector and these new values should be pushed back to another vector.

```
std::vector<int> vector1{10, 20, 30};
auto map = [](int v) { return v * 2; } // double each value
std::vector<int> vector2{...} // there should be 20, 40, 60 as a result
```

Looks easy to do? But I want to do this with 100% efficiency:

1. Output vector should be resized to input vector size before insertion (repeated push_back will check vector capacity each time and this is inefficient)
2. There should be no zero initialization of new vector data before initialization with mapped elements. For example, vector::resize will zero initialize the new vector, which I want to void.

I have a solution using custom iterator and disassembly looks efficient. But maybe I missed something and some standard solution exists.

Comment: there is `std::vector::reserve`

Comment: the zeroing will often be subsequently optimized away by the compiler if you then overwrite the content straight away. Also, don't overestimate the effort that zeroing really is.

Comment: I know that there is std::vector::reserve, yes, it doesn't initialize the data, but also doesn't change the size.

Comment: when you say "will check vector capacity each time" you mean it will have to check if adding one element needs more capacity even though capacity is sufficient? Might be that I misread the question slightly.

Comment: I don't think there's an easier solution that is as performant as the one you have with the custom iterator. Alternatively you can write a custom vector class, use a raw array, or just program in C.

Comment: May be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32199388/what-is-better-reserve-vector-capacity-preallocate-to-size-or-push-back-in-loo

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reserve` which merely reserves capacity but does not construct elements. To transform one vector to another you can use `std::transform` with a `std::back_inserter`:

```
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vector1{10, 20, 30};
    auto map = [](int v) { return v * 2; }; // double each value
    std::vector<int> vector2; // there should be 20, 40, 60 as a result
    vector2.reserve(vector1.size());
    std::transform(vector1.begin(),vector1.end(),std::back_inserter(vector2),map);
    for (const auto& e : vector2) std::cout << e << " ";
}
```

I am not sure if using `emplace` instead of the `back_inserter` would be more efficient. Unfortunately there is nothing like a `back_emplacer`, so you would need to write a manual loop. For `int`s it certainly won't make a difference.

Comment: Tried your solution in Compiler Explorer: Clang optimized capacity checks away with -O3, but GCC doesn't.

Comment: @mdr I am not sure if I understand what you are trying to optimize for, but maybe `std::unique_ptr<int[]>` instead of the vector is what you are looking for.

Comment: It looks that c++ compilers aren't able to handle such kind optimizations of std::vector yet and standard library doesn't have simple and efficient solution. Sure, there are custom iterators and C arrays & etc. to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could just create `vector2` with a given size, then fill it with `std::transform`.

You could as well reuse `vector1` if you are no longer going to use it.

https://godbolt.org/z/GsroG1WeG

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vector1{10, 20, 30};
    std::vector<int> vector2(vector1.size());
    std::transform(cbegin(vector1), cend(vector1), begin(vector2), [](auto n){ return n*2; });
    std::copy(cbegin(vector2), cend(vector2), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
}
```

Comment: Still doing memset in the vector2 constructor: https://godbolt.org/z/efba7bbe8